# "Theme My Login" plugin is not showing login page still receiving [userpro template=login]

Tags: wordpress

*UserPro plugin which was causing continuously "Data Could not Retrieve". So, we have deactivated the UserPro plugin and install the "Theme My Login" plugin.*

After activate the new plugin we are still facing the error on login page [userpro template=login]. Kindly guide me how can solve this problem and user can login into website.

Refer error image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a88XM.jpg).

Comment: go to login page and remove sort code of userpro from editor  and use theme my login shot code.

Comment: thanks for reply, please tell me in details as i have only little knowledge of wordpress.

Comment: please follow answer provided by @sanny

Comment: i have tried his instructions but still the same issue.

Comment: delete userPro plugin

Comment: @AshPatel UserPro plugin deleted as per above advise but still the same login issue.

Comment: as per error displaying in image content from editor have not been changed and its still printing [userpro template=login]. so have a look and try to update page content as per below answer. if you have updated it then above code should not be display. you might have updated content on different page.

Comment: @AshPatel thanks for help isssue has been solved, in "Theme My Login" login link was login-2 but i was linking login only. Thanks for help.

Comment: glad you solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Edit the profile page and remove all the content from login pag.

2) If edited, add thememylogin shortcode [theme-my-login]

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: thanks for reply, please tell me in details as i have only little knowledge of wordpress. i have edit in profile page and added [theme-my-login] code and after update still the same issue. Kindly help.

Comment: did you put [theme-my-login] in content area? and had deleted the old content? are you sure you are checking the same page from frontend?

Comment: i did the same as instructed and problem was solved.

Comment: @RazaJaveid If solved, please select it as Answer (click tick icon next to my comment) & mark it useful (Click ^ Button next to my comment)...Glad it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: added as per your reply.